# Java WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: webdriver

I'm trying to use this line:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

but I'm getting cannot be resolved to a type error for both classes.
What library am I supposed to import?

Comment: add the error stack in question

Comment: have you pass gecko driver?

Answer (score 0):

Download chromedriver from below URL :-

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.31/

Full code will be like below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Edit the path of gecko driver as per your location of geckodriver

Comment: explain to me how to do this please

Comment: I have updated my answer .. you need to download chromedriver from above url .. now you need to pass the location of chromedriver in first line of code ...

Comment: As an explanation ... The chrome need a driver which help chrome to automate using script .. these script send instructions to chromedriver and then chromedriver instruct chrome to perform action .. this happen between api calls between them

Comment: Refer chormedriver import from below url :- https://www.dunnsolutions.com/content/app-dev-blog/-/blogs/576187